# Have trouble consistently updating child element using @Input property

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to update the data source in `loans.component.ts` whenever a new loan is submitted from `loan-form.component.ts`.

So in `loan-form.component.ts` I have this being called when the form submits

```
onSubmit() {
  var config = {
    headers : {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
      }
    }
    this.http
      .post(this.getHostUrl(), JSON.stringify(this.model), config).subscribe();
    this.loanAdded.emit(true);
}
```

Where

```
@Output() loanAdded : EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();
```

Then in `loans-component.ts` I have

```
@Input()
set refreshData (value: boolean) {        
    this.refresh();
}
```

Where

```
refresh() {
    console.log('refresh');
    this.getLoans().subscribe((loans) => {
        this.loans = loans;
        this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(loans);
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
        this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
    });
}
```

It is *kind of* working, but its very intermittent.

- In Firefox and Edge, it works on the 2nd submit and then seemingly randomly thereafter
- In Chrome it works consistently

I have also tried adding the folowing:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    this.refresh();
}
ngOnInit() {
    this.refresh();
}
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.refresh();
}
```

And I can see in the console that `refresh` is called 3 times whenever I submit the form, but the grid does not always get updated...

I also have this method to delete rows and then update, and it works perfectly:

```
removeSelectedRows() {
    this.selection.selected.forEach(item => {
        // console.log(item);
        this.http.delete(this.getHostUrl() + '/' + item.Id).subscribe();
    });
    this.ngOnChanges(null);
    this.refresh();
    this.selection = new SelectionModel<Loan>(true, []);
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
onSubmit() {
  var config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
    }
  }
  this.http
    .post(this.getHostUrl(), JSON.stringify(this.model), config).subscribe();
  this.loanAdded.emit(true);
}
```

The `this.http.post` is async in nature and `this.loanAdded.emit` is sync.

`this.loanAdded.emit` will run even before you've gotten the response from `this.http.post`. So to fix it, write `this.loanAdded.emit` inside the `subscribe` block. Something like this:

```
onSubmit() {
  var config = {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8;'
    }
  }
  this.http.post(this.getHostUrl(), JSON.stringify(this.model), config)
    .subscribe(() => this.loanAdded.emit(true));
}
```

With this, you're only going to emit once you've gotten the response from your POST call. Hence you'll be sure that the DATA on the backend has updated.